# jQuery tmpl: handling null/undefined elements

Tags: undefined, jquery-templates

I have a data structure returned by a web service.  It's a few levels deep, and could have null instead of the expected object.  Which results in some ugly code to check.

```
<td>{{if FulfilledBy}}${FulfilledBy.Name}{{/if}}</td>
```

I can't change the output of the service, but I'd rather not need to check if `FulfilledBy` exists prior to access the `.Name` property.

Is there a better way to write this?  I would have preferred something like

```
<td>${(FulfilledBy || {}).Name}</td>
```

but it doesn't work either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to docs, you can use expressions within `${}`. Have you tried `${FulfilledBy? FulfilledBy.Name: 'no name'}`?